# Pass proxy objects(function) with pre-set variables from main program to subprocesses using Process or Pool Multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am working on a PyQt5 Interface with some calculation functions as its backend. The program takes some inputs from GUI and generate math functions then passed to the backend calculation part where I used multiprocessing. The problem is that the subprocesses or Pool, instead of taking the modified math functions, they take the original functions. I tried dozens of methods but none worked and most of them focus on how to retrieve objects from subprocesses, not in reverse.

I made a simple reproduce of it. Hope someone could find a solution or have suggestions on how to archive parallelism in other ways. Many thanks in advance.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class test_f():
    def __init__(self,a):
        global b
        b=a

    def f1(self,l):
        return b*l
    def f2(self,l):
        return b*b*l

    def get(self):
        return b
class MyManager(BaseManager):
     pass

MyManager.register('func',test_f)


def cal(para):
    #with lock:
    x=para[0]
    func=para[1]

    #setup(k.value)
    print(func,a)
    print(func.f1(x)+func.f2(x))


if __name__=='__main__':

    manager=MyManager()
    manager.start()
    func=manager.func(2)
    p = mp.Process(target=cal, args=[(1,func),])
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: It looks like you want `b` to be a member of `func_c`, I dont' think you want to make it a global. Try replacing `b` wtih `self.b` eg `self.b = a`, `return self.b * self.b * l`.

Comment: eh, I've tried that way. These two expressions are almost the same under this circumstance.

Comment: You question is not clear, what's the result you expect? How is it different than what you get? Except where you try to print `a`, an undefined variable, your code does exactly what I'd expect it to do. What's the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You're right. But in the real project, I have to put these manager things in cal functions, not the main function, do you have any idea how I can start the manager in a function?

Comment: Starting the manager in a function shouldn't be an issue, but based on the question you've asked I'm not even sure you need manager. The managers are a bit advanced and can be avoided for many use cases.

We can't really red your mind here at stack overflow :), if you put time into asking a clear question that lays out your needs and requirements you'll get much better answers.

Comment: Sure you are right. I am quite new to python and multiprocessing, so rather confused with all these things. Actually, on Windows, the manager.start() can only be called in the main part. And yes, I can simply pass the class obj, but in both ways( using manager or not), it seems that the program takes loads of time to deal with this shared class. I'll take time to reconsider it and edit this post tomorrow morning. Much thanks anyway.